# Entries in JBPM Tables

Tags: java, jbpm

I deployed a simple Jpdl (JBPM4.4) and when i check the jbpm database. I found entries in  JBPM4_DEPLOYMENT, JBPM4_DEPLOYPROP tables but not in anyothe table.
I want to understand when the entries goes into the other tables of jbpm database.

Answer (score 0):

> You will find the database scripts for a lot of the supported
>   databases in the DB subproject. The database scripts for PostgreSQL
>   are found in the folder '${JBPM_SDK_HOME}/jbpm-db/build/mysql/scripts.
>   The creation script is called 'postgresql.create.sql'. Using
>   DBVisualizer, you can load this script by switching to the 'SQL
>   Commander' tab and then selecting 'File->Load...'. In the following
>   dialog, navigate to the creation script file.

[image]

Resource Link: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/thejbpmdatabase.html

*You will also get mysql data import related info step by step in this link.*